# Can I compare the equality of an array with an ArrayList of arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have arrays of integers:

```
int[] arrA = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int[] arrB1= {7,3,4,1,5,8,9,2,6};
int[] arrB2= {9,5,1,4,7,6,8,2,3};
int[] arrB3= {4,6,1,3,8,9,5,7,2};
int[] arrB4= {2,3,1,5,8,9,4,6,7};
int[] arrB5= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

and all the `arrB`s are added to the list, as follows:

```
List<int[]> list= new ArrayList<int[]>();

list.add(arrB1);
list.add(arrB2);
list.add(arrB3);
list.add(arrB4);
list.add(arrB5);
```

and I want to compare the equality of the array `arrA` with the list of arrays and I did it using this code:

```
boolean isEqual=false;
for(int index=0; index<list.size(); index++){
    if(list.get(index).equals(arrA)){
          isEqual=true;
    }
    System.out.println(isEqual);
}
```

I know that `arrB5` is equal to `arrA` but why is it that I always get false? Am I doing the comparison right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling `equals` on arrays - which will just compare by *reference*, as arrays don't override `equals`. You want [`Arrays.equals(int[], int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) to compare the values within the arrays.

(You don't need `deepEquals` in this case as you're dealing with `int[]` - and indeed calling `deepEquals` wouldn't compile, as an `int[]` isn't an `Object[]`.)

Comment: At first this was confusing, as I thought the whole point of `equals` was to test for value equality, but since arrays aren't classes in the same way most other objects are they can't really override `Object.equals` (which checks for reference equality), so in the end it made sense. Very counter-intuitive, however, for `equals` to work like that.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart. [Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) is indeed a class. Just that it doesn't override `equals` method.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: Well arrays *could* have been implemented to override `equals` (and `hashCode` and `toString`) - it's just not the way the language was designed. Possibly a mistake; possibly not... but too late to change now.

Answer (score 2):

[ArrayUtils.isEquals()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang) does exactly that. It also handles multi-dimensional arrays.

You also should try `Arrays.deepEquals(a, b)`

Answer (score 0):

according to java.sun.com
The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true). 
It doesn't perform an intelligent comparison for most classes unless the class overrides it. It has been defined in a meaningful way for most Java core classes. If it's not defined for a (user) class, it behaves the same as ==. 
so try Arrays.equals(arrB5,arrA).